# Programar tarea programa en cpanel para ejecuar cronjobs laravel

Tags: laravel, cronjobs, artisan

He creado mi primera command en laravel pero no consigo ejecutarlo desde el cpanel.

En local ejecuto el command sin problemas con el siguiente código:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

Desde el Cpanel no consigo dar con el problema. He probado bastantes códigos sin éxito. La tarea  finaliza sin errores pero la lógica del comando no se ejecuta

Al no mostrar ningún error en la ejecución no se por donde puede estar fallando.

Me da la impresión que el problema puede venir por la ruta al proyecto ya que mi Cpanel no se parece mucho a de los ejemplos que estoy encontrando

Este es el editor de tareas programadas de mi Cpanel.

Entiendo que debo usar la opción "Ejecutar un comando"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No veo muy clara cual es la ruta a mi proyecto desde el administrador de archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que he abierto un archivo del proyecto laravel para determinar la ruta  al proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que supongo que debería usar para ejecutar el artisan schedule seria el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/local/php55/bin/php-cli /var/www/vhosts/buendialogistica.com/pruebas.buendialogistica.com/proyecto-laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

He conseguido ejecutar el comando scheule:run mediante una tarea programada "ejecutar un script php"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ejecuta la lógica del comando pero este no se repite como he indicado en el kernel, solo se ejecuta una sola vez.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('registered:users')->everyMinute();
}
```

Agradecería vuestra ayuda, llevo bastante rato intentando configurar la ejecución el comando y ya no se donde mas buscar.

Comment: Mm no me suena a que esa sea la ruta correcta, prueba imprimiendo en alguna parte de tu proyecto un public path: `dd(public_path())`.

Comment: @Aarón Gutiérrez Gracias por tu comentario, he obtenido la ruta de mi proyecto con el comando que me indicas, pero sigo sin ser capaz de ejecutar el artisan schedule

Comment: ¿Cuál es la ruta completa de tu proyecto?, ¿me lo puedes proporcionar por favor?

Comment: @Aarón Gutiérrez Al ejecutar el comando que me indicaste, "public_path", me arroja la siguiente ruta: /var/www/vhosts/buendialogistica.com/pruebas.buendialogistica.com/proyecto-laravel/public

Comment: si ya estas ejecutando la tarea desde el crontab para que ejecutarla tambien desde laravel :v solo dile al crontab que se ejecute cada minuto!

Comment: @Bryro La idea es tener varios comandos y que cada uno se ejecute en diferentes lapsos de tiempo. Si no comprendí mal esa es la funcionalidad del schedule, con un solo cron ejecutar varios comandos a diferentes con diferentes tiempos de repetición o no.